# How to enable IP spoofing by Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to achieve IP spoofing as guide in Blazemeter tutorial
I did it successfully by single IP but when I configure more that one IP through CSV file then I am  not able to achieve the desired result.

only single IP is displaying in the access log.

It is clear from JMeter that 2 requests are generating from different IPs

**Screenshot1:**

[image]

**Screenshot2:**

[image]

```
2016/08/22 12:11:40 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test! 
2016/08/22 12:11:40 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: [] 
2016/08/22 12:11:40 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true,*local*) 
2016/08/22 12:11:40 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : Thread Group 
2016/08/22 12:11:40 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 1 threads for group Thread Group. 
2016/08/22 12:11:40 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error 
2016/08/22 12:11:40 INFO  - jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group number 1 threads 1 ramp-up 1 perThread 1000.0 delayedStart=false 
2016/08/22 12:11:40 INFO  - jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1 
2016/08/22 12:11:40 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started 
2016/08/22 12:11:40 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-1 
2016/08/22 12:11:40 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Stored: D:\apache-jmeter-3.0\apache-jmeter-3.0\bin\IP.csv 
2016/08/22 12:11:40 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHCAbstractImpl: Local host = IAPC76 
2016/08/22 12:11:40 INFO  - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl: HTTP request retry count = 0 
2016/08/22 12:11:42 INFO  - jmeter.util.BeanShellTestElement: Ip should behttp://localhost:8080/ 
2016/08/22 12:11:43 INFO  - jmeter.util.BeanShellTestElement: Ip should behttp://localhost:8080/ 
2016/08/22 12:11:43 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Stop Thread seen: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterStopThreadException: End of file detected 
2016/08/22 12:11:43 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-1 
2016/08/22 12:11:43 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test 
2016/08/22 12:11:43 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Close: D:\apache-jmeter-3.0\apache-jmeter-3.0\bin\IP.csv 
2016/08/22 12:11:43 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false,*local*) 
2016/08/22 12:12:16 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Running the test! 
2016/08/22 12:12:16 INFO  - jmeter.samplers.SampleEvent: List of sample_variables: [] 
2016/08/22 12:12:16 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(true,*local*) 
2016/08/22 12:12:16 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting ThreadGroup: 1 : Thread Group 
2016/08/22 12:12:16 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Starting 1 threads for group Thread Group. 
2016/08/22 12:12:16 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Thread will continue on error 
2016/08/22 12:12:16 INFO  - jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup: Starting thread group number 1 threads 1 ramp-up 1 perThread 1000.0 delayedStart=false 
2016/08/22 12:12:16 INFO  - jmeter.threads.ThreadGroup: Started thread group number 1 
2016/08/22 12:12:16 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: All thread groups have been started 
2016/08/22 12:12:16 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread started: Thread Group 1-1 
2016/08/22 12:12:16 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Stored: D:\apache-jmeter-3.0\apache-jmeter-3.0\bin\IP.csv 
2016/08/22 12:12:34 INFO  - jmeter.util.BeanShellTestElement: Ip should behttp://192.168.1.140:8080/ 
2016/08/22 12:12:34 INFO  - jmeter.util.BeanShellTestElement: Ip should behttp://192.168.1.140:8080/ 
2016/08/22 12:12:34 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Stop Thread seen: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterStopThreadException: End of file detected 
2016/08/22 12:12:34 INFO  - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Thread finished: Thread Group 1-1 
2016/08/22 12:12:34 INFO  - jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine: Notifying test listeners of end of test 
2016/08/22 12:12:34 INFO  - jmeter.services.FileServer: Close: D:\apache-jmeter-3.0\apache-jmeter-3.0\bin\IP.csv 
2016/08/22 12:12:34 INFO  - jmeter.gui.util.JMeterMenuBar: setRunning(false,*local*)
```

Comment: Can you show how you configured your HTTP Request (show all tabs) and in view results tree show all tabs for this sample

Comment: In Basic Tab i just gave my vanila server url as 192.168.1.140 ....In Advance tab i did parameterised IPs in variable ${ID} coming through CSV  file

Comment: Can you show jmeter.log content ?

Comment: I added the log details...please refer the screenshot

Comment: can you run again your plan and show jmeter.log (full file as txt not screenshot) thx

Comment: Please refer log content

Comment: Everything looks ok, maybe you should report a bug with all these information. Try making a Wireshark capture also. Did you try using jmeter 2.13 ? thx